# Class not found using custom composer package

Tags: php, composer-php

I have created a custom comoposer package and I want to use it on my project with this composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "papillon/test",
    "type": "library",
    "version": "dev-master",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.11"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Papillon\\Fountaine\\Eau\\": "src/Papillon/Fountaine/Eau/"
        }
    }  
}
```

I compress it in zip. In the main project, I add a folder called repo, where I add de composer package zip. Then, I modify the composer.json of the main project like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "artifact",
            "url": "var/main/repo"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "papillon/test": "dev-master"
    }
    
}
```

I execute composer update and the pakage is added to vendor folder; all seems to be going well... but if I want to test the package from the main project with this script:

```
<?php

require (__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
use Papillon\Fountaine\Eau\FlowerClass;

echo FlowerClass::bloom();
```

It returns: *PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Papillon\Fountaine\Eau\FlowerClass' not found in .../test_package.php:6
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
thrown in .../test_package.php on line 6*

I think that the package may not be recognized by the main project; maybe the package was improperly installed in the main project?

Comment: Do you use xdebug? I find that setting a break point and stepping through the composer autoloader can be pretty useful for finding issues with autoloading.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Can you find that file within the `vendor` folder?

Comment: I debugged the composer autoload adding breakpoints and I discovered that in the autoload package route path there was a folder with lowercase name instead of uppercase, as it was defined in the composer.json of the package. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging autoload can be very useful to catch errors. Take care with the route paths, the autoload tryed to find the classes files in a path with a lowercase folder when in the package composer.json the route was definded with that folder uppercase.